# Issue with Apache Poi Error in AEM Service Pack 6.5.9

Tags: java, aem

recently we installed the latest service pack (6.5.9) and we're getting issues related to Apache Poi where the createWorkbook method is not working due to NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/compress/utils/InputStreamStatistics. Attached would be the logged error :[Error Log for Apache Poi](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I52Y3.png)

We've tried to use the latest Apache Poi's dependencies but the error still persist:
[Apache Poi dependencies in pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FWa57.png)

The current UberJar version would be : 6.5.9-1.0 as shown on the release notes for the latest AEM 6.5.9 service pack:[uberJar dependencies in pom.xml](https://i.stack.imgur.com/opoCH.png)

Any help/feedback is much appreciated and thanks in advance!

Comment: Hi and welcome. Posting pictures of code or errors on SO is a bad practice.

Comment: @Renis1235 Hi Renis, noted on that but may i know the reason why behind it as i am still new to SO?

Comment: https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Answer (score 0):

You are missing `org.apache.commons.compress`, which might be removed with the SP9. Currently it is part of AEM. (I haven't tested SP9 yet)

To fix it, you need to embed this bundle manually. Just like you did it with Apache POI (which is also not part of AEM). Depending on your Maven build, it might be enough, to remove the `<scope>provided</scope>` from the dependencies. Just search for org.apache.commons.compress in your pom.xml's, to find out how you did it.

[image]

Comment: Hello Alexander, i've already manaully embed the commons compress bundle in my maven pom.xml but the error still persist.

Comment: Have you checked, if it is available? E.g. with a test-servlet? How did you embed it (directly in you bundle with the POI-libs, or as its own bundle)? Have you manually extracted your packages and bundle.jar's, to check it is really part of you deployment?

Comment: The issue has been resolved by running the quickstart script after the service pack upgrade. Thanks!